# Is there a memory leak in this code?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

This is my code in C++:

```
bool** p = new bool *[row];
for(int i=0; i<row; ++i) field[i] = new bool[column];
i=0;
while(i<100){
    p = newArray();
    i++;
}
```

Is there any memory leak in this code? Should I add "delete p;" in the while loop?

---

If I change the code:

```
p = new bool *[row];
for(int i=0; i<row; ++i) field[i] = new bool[column];
i=0;
while(i<100){
    delete p;
    p = newArray();
    i++;
}
```

Is there still memory leaks?

Comment: You should use RAII instead.

Comment: Are we supposed to *guess* what `newArray()` does? Does it call `std::terminate()`? In that case there's no leak.

Comment: Yes, you never `delete` your variable `p` anywhere, then you overwrite it.

Comment: Without knowing what newArray() does, who can tell what actually happens - clearly, to not leak original p, you would have to free it somewhere. And assigning a new value from newArray is most likely causing a leak.

Comment: No, it just return a new array.

Comment: There is no memory leak, since the code should not even compile. The result of the expression `new bool[x][y]` cannot be converted to `bool**`.

Comment: It is of course possible that the original allocation failed, in which case there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. If you don't use smart pointers, or don't have a `delete/delete[]` for every `new/new[]`, then you're leaking. If you lose handles on allocated resources, you're leaking (like you're doing in the code). Your original memory is lost because you no longer have a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a memory leak as soon as there is no pointer left in the program which remembers the address of the dynamically allocated memory. (And of course, you don't delete the memory anywhere either.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are leaking the original array allocated using `new bool[x][y]`.

There could be further leaks. In particular, `p = newArray()` without a matching deallocation looks suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely leaking memory.  (I get what you mean by the program flow, so I've taken the liberty of correcting it)..

```
field = new bool *[row];  // <- array created and assigned to "field".
for(int i=0; i<row; ++i) field[i] = new bool[column];
i=0;
while(i<100){
    field = newArray();  // <- the previously-created array is leaked here, as well as
    i++;                 // any new arrays created by previous iterations of "newArray()"
}
```

Assuming that `newArray()` returns a new allocation, then `delete[] field` in the lower loop will free `field` correctly, but the arrays in each row of `field` will still be leaked.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: it's from his code.  I'm answering the conceptual question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i<100){
    p = newArray();
    i++;
}
```

pointer p is overwritten everytime, so it's classic memory leak.

```
p = new bool *[row];
for(int i=0; i<row; ++i) field[i] = new bool[column];
i=0;
while(i<100){
   delete p;
   p = newArray();
   i++;
}
```

If p points to previous `new bool *[row]` and `newArray` calls new [] to allocate memory but you call `delete p`, it's undefined behavior. You should call `delete [] p;`.

If `newArray` calls new to allocate memory, the while loop releases 99 memory block, after while loop, you still need to call `delete p;`

Remember new/delete, new []/delete[] must be called in pair in program, otherwise there is memory leak; pointer overwritten will cause memory leak.